# Dumping memory on AIX

Tags: memory, aix, memory-dump

I have an AIX 5.3 Server that has multiple users.

Is there a way I can dump the memory of a specific user or a specific process?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a core with the gecore command:

`gencore <pid of process> <file_name>`

Make sure that full core dump suport is enabled or enable it before with:

`chdev -l sys0 -a fullcore=true`